# Process finished with exit code 1 and exception Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods'

Tags: java, spring-boot

tengo un microservicio hecho con Spring Boot mediante el Ide Intelij. El microservicio consulta y graba datos en una base de datos mysql local ( bueno es lo que estoy intentando)
Hola, si disculpa.  Al ejecutar el main es cuando me da ese error. Gracias

> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException:
>   Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication] is
>   declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in
>   annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.(AnnotationUtils.java:2180)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.from(AnnotationUtils.java:2148)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.getOtherDescriptors(AnnotationUtils.java:2312)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.getAttributeAliasNames(AnnotationUtils.java:2299)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasNames(AnnotationUtils.java:1813)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAttributeAliasMap(AnnotationUtils.java:1722)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.postProcessAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationUtils.java:1335)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:365)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:121)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:93)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:72)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:717)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE] at
>   com.sinbugs.contacts.ContactsWsApplication.main(ContactsWsApplication.java:13)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils$AliasDescriptor.(AnnotationUtils.java:2173)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] ... 23 common frames
>   omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

---

La clase que contiene el main es la siguiente:

package com.sinbugs.contacts;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContactsWsApplication {

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ContactsWsApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

---

El controller es el siguiente  ( lo he puesto por poner porque el error me lo da solo al hacer el run del la aplicacion)

```
package com.sinbugs.contacts.api;

import com.sinbugs.contacts.dto.Contact;
import com.sinbugs.contacts.service.ContactService;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.dozer.Mapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ContactsApi {

    @Autowired
    ContactService contactService;

    // Inyecta mapper de Dozer
    @Autowired
    Mapper mapper;


    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ContactResponse updateOrSave(@RequestBody @Valid final ContactRequest contactRequest){
        // Mapeo request dto ==> entity
        final Contact contact = this.mapper.map(contactRequest, Contact.class);

        // Invoca l[ogica de negocio
        final Contact updatedContact = this.contactService.save(contact);

        // Mapeo entity ==> response dto
        final ContactResponse contactResponse = this.mapper.map(updatedContact, ContactResponse.class);

        return contactResponse;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/contact", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Contact getById(){
        return new Contact(1L, "John", "Doe", "+57 311 222 3344", "john@sinbugs.com");

    }
}
```

---

El pom.xml es:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.sinbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>contacts-ws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>contacts-ws</name>
<description>Servicio web REST simple</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image: Pantallazo del error que da, al ejecutar el main]

Comment: Podrias hacer la pregunta? como te paso, en que IDE, haciendo que. Asi podran ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, si disculpa. El IDE es intelij. El proyecto es un microservicio que consulta y graba datos en una base de datos mysql local. Al ejecutar el main es cuando me da ese error. Gracias

Comment: Coloca el codigo y explica donde falla, para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: @Ramiro Barone . He añadido el código gracias.

Comment: He añadido algunos de los ficheros de los fuentes, y una imagen de cuando me da el error, y mas información adicional. Estoy bloqueado. por favor que alguien me ayude con este error. Si alguien necesita los ficheros completos para probarlo en local que me diga. gracias